# Cannot get library to work in Arduino Uno r3 although it looks like it's installed correctly

Tags: libraries, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have an arduino uno r3 connected to a water level sensor and a simple (or so I thought) script to check the functionality and send the data to ThingSpeak. I installed the library (I am using arduino IDE 2.2.1), I can see it in Sketch>Include Library>Contributed libraries and I included it in the script, but I still get

fatal error: ThingSpeak.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
Compilation error: ThingSpeak.h: No such file or directory

This is my code in question:

```
#include <ThingSpeak.h>

int respin = A5;
int resval = 0;
int channelId = 240XXXX;
const char *apiKey = "0EOS6PL89MXXXXXX";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ThingSpeak.begin(client);
}

void loop() {
  resval = analogRead(respin);

  if (resval <= 300) {
    Serial.println("Bowl is almost empty! Refill!!!");
  } else if (resval > 300 && resval <= 330) {
    Serial.println("Water level is medium.");
  } else if (resval > 330) {
    Serial.println("Water level is high.");
  }

  // Update ThingSpeak fields
  ThingSpeak.setField(1, resval);  // Raw sensor reading
  ThingSpeak.setField(2, resval <= 300 ? 1 : (resval > 300 && resval <= 330 ? 2 : 3));  
  // Water level status

  ThingSpeak.writeFields(channelId, apiKey);

  delay(1000);
}
```

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling/manually adding the library, restarting the IDE etc to no avail. I am very new to this so any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `ThingSpeak.begin(client)` requires an Ethernet or WiFi client, do you have an Ethernet shield or WiFi shield other than your Arduino Uno? If you have, you are missing some initialisation code and to include the shield's library. Refer to the examples came with ThingSpeak library for more details.

Comment: I don't have either shield unfortunatelly but I ended up passing the data through a raspberry instead. Thank you for the answer though :) I would literally be glaring at my code still since not a single tutorial I saw mentioned it